# node.js openssl wrapper (not cli)

Tags: node.js, openssl

Dose Node.JS have an openssl binding / wrapper that does not spawn the openssl via shell? Maybe some cpp addon or something. I am looking specifically for an openssl binding and not a pure js library like forge.

Answer (score 0):

The built in node crypto library uses openssl. Which means that openssl libraries are always present so you can call them like any other c library like [this library does](https://github.com/indutny/raw-ecdsa)

Comment: But it doesn't provide access to 100% of the functionality of the openssl binary